# Grep within Perl substitution (RHS)

Tags: perl, grep, substitution

*I would like to replace text based on a "string string" pairs defined in file $key.*

Sample Input file **$input**

```
a b c foo
d e f moo
g h i boo
```

Predefined "Key" file **$key**

```
cow moo
code foo
ghost boo
cheer woo
```

Desired Output

```
a b c code
d e f cow
g h i ghost
```

## My Attempt

```
perl -pe 's/(.*?)(\woo)/$1qq{grep -oP ".*(?=\s$2)" $key}/e' $input > $output
```

error returned

```
syntax error at -e line 1, near "$1qq{grep -oP ".*(?=\s$2)" $key}"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/(.*?)(\woo)/$1qq{grep -oP ".*(?=\s$2)" $key}/ee"
```

*Any help would be appreciated.*

*Suggestions for a better approach to achieve the desired result are very much welcome, but an accepted answer would ideally* also *include a solution or comment on using perl substition.*

Answer (score 4):

Using perl from command line,

```
perl -lane'
  BEGIN{ local @ARGV = pop; %h = reverse map split, <> }
  print join " ", @F[0..2], $h{$F[3]};

' input key
```

output

```
a b c code
d e f cow
g h i ghost
```

update

```
perl -lane'
  BEGIN{ local @ARGV = pop; %h = reverse map /(.+)\s+(\S+)$/, <> }
  print join " ", @F[0..2], $h{$F[3]};

' input key
```

Comment: Nice neat and short solution, thank you for contributing. I would love to know how you would adapt if the key file lines were `z y x code foo` etc and desired output lines were `a b c z y x code` etc (input lines are the same as before `a b c foo` etc)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can use `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$2]=$1;next} $NF=a[$NF]' key input
a b c code
d e f cow
g h i ghost
```

It reads the `key` file to array `a`
Then print `input` file using keys for array `a` to change last field.

If `a[$NF]` may be `0`, use:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$2]=$1;next} {$NF=a[$NF];print}' key input
```

Comment: That will fail if `a[$NF]` evaluates numerically to zero. +1 for the right approach though.

Answer (score 3):

```
$1qq{grep -oP ".*(?=\s$2)" $key}
```

is not a valid Perl expression. Maybe you meant

```
$1 . qq{grep -oP ".*(?=\s$2)" $key}
```

although there are numerous other errors in that expression. (You used `qq{}` where you should have used `qx{}`, you forgot to escape the `\`, you used `$key` without having assigned a value to it, maybe more.)

Maintainable solution that only reads the key file once:

```
perl -e'
   my %lookup;
   open(my $fh, "<", shift(@ARGV))
      or die $!;

   while (<$fh>) {
      my ($v,$k) = split;
      $lookup{$k} = $v;
   }

   while (<>) {
      my @f = split;

      next if !@f;  # Skip blank lines.

      if (defined($lookup{$f[3]})) {
         warn("Can'\''t find key \"$f[3]\". Copying record unchanged.\n");
         print;
         next;
      }

      $f[3] = $lookup{$f[3]};
      print("@f\n");
   }
' keyfile.txt input.txt >output.txt
```

Comment: does `$1 . qx{grep -oP ".*(?=\s$2)" $key}` work in this case? With this (your) correction, on my machine I get an error, and if I'm not mistaken, the process does not exit (no new prompt, had to ^c). error: `Unrecognized escape \s passed through at -e line 1.`
`Name "main::key" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
`Use of uninitialized value $key in concatenation (.) or string at -e line 1, <> line 1.`

Comment: @okapiho, I hadn't checked if you had made other errors, but it turns out you had. You also forgot to escape the `\ `, and you never assigned a value to `$key`. There could be more.

Comment: For some reason (outside my skill level), for me your `die` on line 14 prints `Can't find \n` instead of `Can't find $f[3]\n`. Otherwise it works great and I was easily able to understand your code, adapt it to my needs, and learn a lot along the way with the help of `perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html`, thank you :)

Comment: It should never print `$F[3]` but its value when it can't find it in the other file. It means one of your records had a blank value for the fourth field, which means one of your records had less than four fields. Maybe you have a blank line?

Comment: Oops, because of the order things were done in, the error message may have been misleading. Fixed the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Personally - I don't like doing one liners, because they're hard to read.

The general trick for pattern replacement is this:

```
my %replacements;
open ( my $keyfile, "<", "key_file.txt" ) or die $!;
while ( $keyfile ) {
     chomp;
     my ( $value, $key ) = split;
     $replacements{$key} = $value; 
}

my $regex = join ( "\b|\b", keys %replacements ); 
$regex = qr/$regex/; 

open ( my $replace_fh, "<", "input_file" ) or die $!; 
while ( <$replace_fh> ) {
    s/\b($regex)\b/$replacements{$1}/g;
    print;
}
```

Which turns your input into a hash of replacements, constructs a regular expression that matches any word in it, and then uses that regex to 'match' - using `$1` a lookup key for the hash.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "Looks like your keys are reversed in your example"? I am not seeing what I think you mean in my example

Comment: @okapiho, He means the key field is usually the first field (`key value`). The order of the columns in your input is unusual (`value key`), but not wrong. I've fixed his code.

Comment: @okapiho, Note: Sobrique's code replaces values in all columns of the input, not just the fourth.